# Feature request: retracting delete vote on answers

Tags: feature-request, answers

When I vote to close a question it's possible to retract close vote. When I press `delete(1)` to remove my vote on an answer, it only asks for confirmation if I want to vote to delete, not retract. Can we please have that as an option?

Comment: Over on [meta.se]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061/270345

Comment: I think if you vote that post up, your deletion vote will be clear. or it will clear all deletion votes if it's get >=0 vote totally (this is tested but for single deletion vote no case to test : ) )

Comment: ... or come back to vote for undelete after deletion performed

Comment: @sddgob I have about 1800 answers, with 56 questions. AskUbuntu has about 300,000 posts. Keeping track of all votes can be nearly impossible and this would be a useful feature. But yes, I see your point.

Comment: not impossible, you have all your deletion votes or other votes here https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/sergiy-kolodyazhnyy?tab=votes&sort=deletion (link is accessible for every user himself/herself +MODs maybe)

Comment: OK, I stand corrected on that one. Most times I don't use that tab though. Still it would be very useful to have undelete vote option.